# Database queues in Asterisk - timeout not being honored

Tags: database, queue, asterisk

I setup dynamic queues in Asterisk according to this: http://libryder.com/Ez7llN

The queues connect successfully and all members are recognized but it always rings to voicemail, never trying the next member.

```
+----+------------+-------------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+--------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
| id | name       | musiconhold | announce | context | timeout | monitor_join | monitor_format | queue_youarenext | queue_thereare | queue_callswaiting | queue_holdtime | queue_minutes | queue_seconds | queue_lessthan | queue_thankyou | queue_reporthold | announce_frequency | announce_round_seconds | announce_holdtime | retry | wrapuptime | maxlen | servicelevel | strategy | joinempty | leavewhenempty | eventmemberstatus | eventwhencalled | reportholdtime | memberdelay | weight | timeoutrestart | ringinuse | setinterfacevar | autofill | timeoutpriority |
+----+------------+-------------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+--------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+
|  5 | 4352754426 | NULL        | NULL     | NULL    |       5 |         NULL | NULL           | NULL             | NULL           | NULL               | NULL           | NULL          | NULL          | NULL           | NULL           | NULL             |               NULL |                   NULL | NULL              |  NULL |       NULL |      0 |         NULL | ringall  | NULL      | NULL           |              NULL |            NULL |           NULL |           0 |   NULL |           NULL |      NULL |             yes | yes      | conf            |
+----+------------+-------------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+--------------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------+--------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+



+----------+------------+------------+---------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| uniqueid | membername | queue_name | interface                 | penalty | paused | hunt_id |
+----------+------------+------------+---------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
|       18 | agent1     | 4352754426 | local/4352151050@outbound |    NULL |   NULL |       5 |
|       19 | agent2     | 4352754426 | local/4352151052@outbound |    NULL |   NULL |       5 |
|       20 | agent3     | 4352754426 | local/4352151054@outbound |    NULL |   NULL |       5 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------------------------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Am I missing some option?

Comment: please paste or link to a call trace

Answer (score 0):

Please try with different ring strategy instead of **ringall** like random or **rrmemory**. And please also check **timeout** field it look too low ?